# ASP.NET page not going to server after button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, image, jcrop

I have an asp.net page that I use in popup. This pop up basically contains two image controls and markup contains the JCrop plugin. From a page, the popup opens and hence the page loads. I am reading image in bytes, converting to base64 and setting it to the src attribute of both the image controls(both have runat='server'). There are 2 buttons in that page. But the click on these buttons are not hitting any event handler like page_load, button_clicked etc.

```
<img id="target" runat="server" alt="Main Image" />
<img id="imgCropped" runat="server" alt="Preview Image" class="jcrop-preview" style="border-color:gray" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        strMIMEType = Session["MIMEType"].ToString();
        strImageData = Session["ImageData"].ToString();
        strImageName = Session["ImageName"].ToString();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string sTemp = "data:" + strMIMEType + ";base64," + strImageData;
            target.Src = sTemp;
            imgCropped.Src = sTemp;
        }
    }
```

Below code is when user selects a image file and hit UploadClick button.

```
protected void btnUploadclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpPostedFile objfile = AsyncUpload.PostedFile;
        if (AsyncUpload.HasFile)
        {
            if (!IsImageValid(objfile))
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ImageNotValid", "alert('Image format is wrong. Please upload JPEG, PNG or GIF images.')");
            else
            {
                Session["ImageData"] = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(objfile.FileName), 0, System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(objfile.FileName).Length);
                Session["MIMEType"] = objfile.ContentType;
                Session["ImageName"] = AsyncUpload.FileName;
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "OpenPopUp", "window.open('ImageCropPopup.aspx', 'CropImage', 'height=450,width=700,left=350,top=170,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,status=no');", true);
            }
        }
        else
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ImageNotUploaded", "alert('Please select an Image.')");
    }
```

It does not hit page_load at all when I click any of the button. Please help.

Comment: Is the .aspx page in the popup referencing the correct code behind file?

Comment: If you load the page directly (ie not via pop up), do the events fire on submit click? You should provide markup for container page as well as pop window page

Comment: @Dennis R, yes it refers to the correct code behind. As I said, from container page, when I call window.open, the popup page opens 1st time correctly and all the code behind events hit their respective handlers. But then after that I crop the image and hit Save(one of the button), then it says page can not be displayed.

Comment: Then it's a different issue altogether. You have to check the code for `Save` button why it results in `page can not be displayed`

Comment: @Jonathan Even if I load the page directly, same thing. To add some more description: In the container page, I have a FileUpload control. User is selecting a file there. I am converting the file to base64 string and assigning to a Session and opening the pop up, where I am accessing it and assigning to src attribute of img tab. Editing the question and including more code.

Comment: Are you saying that if you load the pop up page directly (ie not in a pop up), it doesn't firs the page_load event of the pop up page? Or that you get an error? I would take all of the pop up stuff out of the mix first, and ensure that your page loads correctly on its own. You have some risk of null references there when you deserialize your session variables, is it that?

Comment: Load the page directly or in the pop up, first time it loads correctly and all the server event handler fires. After that, when I hit an asp.net button, I expect it to hit page_load and then button_click event but it does nothing and shows This page can not be displayed message.

Comment: I guess the problem is image size. If image size is less say 500KB it works fine and after load, I crop the image and hit button, it goes to server events and everything works fine. But when I use image more than say 1.5MB, above said problem comes.

Comment: You may also learn more by examining your system event log. The "Page cannot be displayed" error may have more details in the error log. Also, run Fiddler when you click your submit button. You say that the events on the code behind do not get fired; however the error message is displayed, so *something* is happening. Fiddler may provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Once you place an ASP.NET server control button in a jQuery popup you lose the click event in the main page. You have essentially removed the button from the DOM at that point. You can try hiding your server button with jQuery on the main page, replacing the server button with a standard html button then click the server button with the `.trigger` event from jQuery.

Like this:

```
$("#yourHtmlButtonID").click(function(){

   $("#yourServerButtonID").trigger("click");

 });
```

Just remember to hide your server button with jQuery and not ASP.NET's property of `Visible = false` because it won't get rendered to the page if you do.

Comment: I have normal popup window.open, not the jquery pop up. JQuery I am using to crop image and nothing else. I guess the problem is image size. Less than 1MB is good. everything works. Beyond that it bursts.

Comment: Previously, I was uploading the image to a folder under application's root directory and then opening the pop up to crop the image. Now, I want to remove the uploading process of main image because I need just cropped image. So, I removed that code and now I am reading the image selected by user from Fileupload control as bytes, converting it to base64 and then assigning the code to src attribute of img control(runat='server'). Upto here things are working. But after I crop image and hit Save button, it says page can not be displayed. Doesn't even go to page_load event.

Comment: If it blows up with files larger than 1MB maybe you need to increase the file size limit? You can try editing the web.config file with the following `<binding name="basicHttpBinding"  maxReceivedMessageSize="21000000" maxBufferSize="21000000" >`